# luaL_loadfile randomly say "cannot open file.lua : No such file or directory" for existing file

Tags: c, lua

`luaL_loadfile` sometimes unable to find `file.lua`. It's not depend on relative path as I tired `/path/to/file.lua` but received same error:

`"cannot open file.lua : No such file or directory"`

I've used `luaL_loadfile` in `exec_lua_file`.

This problem occurs mostly after calling `exec_lua`. I don't know how can it be related.

```
void exec_lua(char *command, uint8_t trim) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    if (!L) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Lua init error!\n");
        goto end;
    }

    lua_pushinteger(L, a);
    lua_setglobal(L, "a");

    command = command + trim;

    luaL_openlibs(L);
    if(luaL_dostring(L, command)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't execute lua!\n");
        goto end;
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "a");
    a = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

    end:
    lua_close(L);
    return;
}


void exec_lua_file(char *filename, uint8_t trim) {

    char path[1024];

    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    if (!L) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Lua init error!\n");
        goto end;
    }

    lua_pushinteger(L, a);
    lua_setglobal(L, "a");
    filename = filename + trim;
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    getcwd(path, 1024);
    puts(path);

    if(luaL_loadfile(L, filename) || lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        goto end;
    }

    lua_pop(L, lua_gettop(L));
    lua_getglobal(L, "a");
    a = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

    end:
    lua_close(L);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Problem was a space at the end of filename.

Observable here: `"cannot open file.lua : No such file or directory"`